# How to render correct format Schema

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using nextjs.
I want to render `Schema` inside head tag.
I can but it show's `&quot;:&quot` instead of my question.

this is my schema:

```
const Schema = (url,image) => (
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      {JSON.stringify({
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "mainEntityOfPage": {
          "@type": "WebPage",
          "@id": url
        },
        "headline": "Article headline",
        "image": image,
        "datePublished": datePublished,
        "dateModified": dateModified,
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "****"
        },
        "publisher": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "macandental",
          "logo": {
            "@type": "ImageObject",
            "url": "***logo.png"
          }
        }
      })}
    </script>
  );
  
  export default Schema;
```

Inside my component:

```
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
      <title>{seo.title}</title>
        <meta name="title" content={seo.title} />
        <meta name="description" content={seo.description} />
          <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
          <Schema url={"/faq"}/>
      </Head>
....
```

but the result is :

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{&quot;@context&quot;:&quot;https://schema.org&quot;,&quot;@type&quot;:&quot;NewsAr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js escapes certain characters when rendering inside the `Head` component. I think this is a known issue with Next.js and has been discussed [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2006), [here](https://bleepcoder.com/next-js/229591208/escaping-problem-with-meta-tags) and [here.](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/2917)

If that so, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop, which allows you to insert html directly into your component.

Sample execution;

```
const Schema = (url, image) => {
 const schema = JSON.stringify({
   "@context": "https://schema.org",
   "@type": "NewsArticle",
   "mainEntityOfPage": {
     "@type": "WebPage",
     "@id": url
   },
   "headline": "Article headline",
   "image": image,
   "datePublished": datePublished,
   "dateModified": dateModified,
   "author": {
     "@type": "Person",
     "name": "****"
   },
   "publisher": {
     "@type": "Organization",
     "name": "macandental",
     "logo": {
       "@type": "ImageObject",
       "url": "***logo.png"
     }
   }
 });

 return (
   <script type="application/ld+json" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: schema }} />
 );
};

export default Schema;
```

This should prevent Next.js from escaping your JSON-LD schema and rendered correctly. So by doing this, the expected result should be like..

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
 "@context": "https://schema.org",
 "@type": "NewsArticle",
 "mainEntityOfPage": {
   "@type": "WebPage",
   "@id": "/faq"
 },
 "headline": "Article headline",
 "image": "image_url",
 "datePublished": "date_published",
 "dateModified": "date_modified",
 "author": {
   "@type": "Person",
   "name": "****"
 },
 "publisher": {
   "@type": "Organization",
   "name": "macandental",
   "logo": {
     "@type": "ImageObject",
     "url": "***logo.png"
   }
 }
}
</script>
```